# Multiple postgresql Database at runtime in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

When customers is created in my app ruby on rails,I want to create database for each customers without break/closing my exiting/running application database.When particular customer is login then I want to CRUD operations on both databases.
  My app Database name is myapp.
E.g  when customer 1 is created in myapp I want create One database for customer_1.
      when customer 2 is created in myapp I want create One database for customer_2.

When customer 1 is login in myapp , when he does any crud operations then I want save all data in Myapp database as well as customer_1 database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel)

> Sequel is a simple, flexible, and powerful SQL database access toolkit
> for Ruby.
>
> Sequel provides thread safety, connection pooling and a concise DSL
> for constructing SQL queries and table schemas.

i think this tool can help you create many database set on you app

Comment: I have one myapp database , I don't want break exiting app.This is used for reporting purpose

Comment: @ShankarKamble Using Sequel is better as you can create databases on the fly too. You can specify a complete SQL query too using it.

Comment: @JunaidKirkire is there any way create database in postgresql using sequel

Comment: @ShankarKamble if you have connection to database you can create.`DB = Sequel.connect('postgres://user:password@host:port/')` and `DB.run "CREATE DATABASE customer_1 bla bla bla"` read documentations

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use establish_connection (using before_filter in application_controller) http://www.runtime-era.com/2012/11/dynamic-activerecord-database.html

Answer (score 0):

first make another label and put there all setting of databasee in database.yml then in respected model from where you want to connect different database create two different methods and assign their database connection by establish_connection(database.yml files label name here such as "development") and another method put another db name, which location you want to switch database then call these methods.